# syntax error in if()

Tags: php, if-statement

i am trying to write code, but i haven't any conent on page:

```
 <?php
require 'http://bescik.kei.pl/fb2/base.php';
$sqluser = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE fbid='123321'");

if($sqluser){
echo 'super';
}
else
{
echo 'dupa';
};
?>
```

Comment: I like how you end your if()s with a semicolon but not your echo's (thats your error, try `echo "super";`

Comment: you have a PHP error. This is NOT an sql error at all.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo 'super';

echo 'dupa';
```

You're missing a semicolon at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You need semicolons on the following lines:

```
echo 'super'
```

and

```
echo 'dupa'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are relying on:

```
require 'http://bescik.kei.pl/fb2/base.php';
```

for your database connection, your code will always fail / echo `dupa`.

When you include / require an external file like `http://bescik.kei.pl/fb2/base.php`, your script will send an http request to that server for that file, see the manual on [`include`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php). That server will parse / execute the php before it sends the result so you will end up including a file without any php in it. It will contain at most some html, depending on what the `base.php` script outputs.